# Can't get player id using one signal, tried every solution available on here

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

i tried everything and it either returns nil or it doesn't access the OSsubscribtion listener , this is my finishlaunch in my app delegate file. I tried every solution available online and nothing works , my Onesignal version is >= 2.6.2 and <3.0

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()
      OneSignal.add(self as OSSubscriptionObserver)


    let notificationReceivedBlock: OSHandleNotificationReceivedBlock = { notification in

         print("Received Notification: \(notification!.payload.notificationID)")
      }

      let notificationOpenedBlock: OSHandleNotificationActionBlock = { result in
         // This block gets called when the user reacts to a notification received
         let payload: OSNotificationPayload = result!.notification.payload

         var fullMessage = payload.body
         print("Message = \(fullMessage)")

         if payload.additionalData != nil {
            if payload.title != nil {
               let messageTitle = payload.title
                  print("Message Title = \(messageTitle!)")
            }

            let additionalData = payload.additionalData
            if additionalData?["actionSelected"] != nil {
               fullMessage = fullMessage! + "\nPressed ButtonID: \(additionalData!["actionSelected"])"
            }
         }
      }

      let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false,
         kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: true]

      OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
         appId: "My app id i removed",
         handleNotificationReceived: notificationReceivedBlock,
         handleNotificationAction: notificationOpenedBlock,
         settings: onesignalInitSettings)

      OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification





  OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
    if(accepted){

    }else{

    }
  })



    return true


}
```

and this is my listener in app delegate file, i added this because i want it to detect any change in subscription state that happens

```
 func onOSSubscriptionChanged(_ stateChanges: OSSubscriptionStateChanges!) {
    if !stateChanges.from.subscribed && stateChanges.to.subscribed {
       print("Subscribed for OneSignal push notifications!")
    }
    print("SubscriptionStateChange: \n\(stateChanges)")


    if let playerId = stateChanges.to.userId {
       print("Current playerId \(playerId)")
    }
 }
```

Comment: it alse gives this in error window.    SubscriptionStateChange: 
Optional(<OSSubscriptionStateChanges:
from: <OSSubscriptionState: userId: (null), pushToken: (null), userSubscriptionSetting: 1, subscribed: 0>,
to:   <OSSubscriptionState: userId: (null), pushToken: 24bbe8cead9802dec9f5bda99724d488441a98b85a1ce972a298b98648cacff4, userSubscriptionSetting: 1, subscribed: 0>

Comment: Firebase doesn't really seem to be part of the issue here, so I removed the tag.  If it is actually relevant, please edit the question to explain how Firebase is involved and affects the code you've written.